# How can I make GDB print a string literally (without escaping)?

Tags: gdb

I have a big, long string that I want to capture to a file. I can use logging to get most of the way there:

```
set logging on
set logging file gdb.log
```

…but if I use `p` or `x/s` to print the string, quotes and junk are all escaped. How can I get the string as-is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a *really* large string you can also use:

```
(gdb) set variable $s = MY_STRING
(gdb) dump binary memory FILE $s $s + (size_t)strlen($s)
```

which can be easily adapted to handle buffers with null bytes. Also the content of FILE would never contain anything other than the string.

Answer (score 7):

Ah, I totally forgot about `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n", some_string
```

Comment: Neat idea, but I can't figure out how to redirect this into a file.

Comment: @mehaase, simple:
`set logging file str_dump.txt`

`set logging on`

`set logging redirect on`
The first two lines instruct gdb to write output to the file (in addition to writing to the terminal), the last line disables output to the terminal.